Is DUI a strict liability offense?
I am watching a video about people impacted by the auto-brewery syndrome.
It's a condition where sugar gets converted into alcohol by the body without any consumption.
Some get arrested for it while driving while not knowing they are impacted by the condition.
Does DUI count on the defendant actively drinking alcohol?
Could, based on the unknowing of the condition, defendants be acquitted because they didn't actually drink alcohol?
All jurisdictions welcome

I suppose that this could also extend to people who DUI as a result of someone else spiking their non-alcoholic drink with intoxicating drugs without their knowledge or consent.

First-time or subsequent offense? The first time, they might not have known. The second time, they would have known.

@o.m. That condition is quite hard to diagnose, but let's assume first time offense.

In Germany there is a relevant crime and a misdemeanor. The crime punishes unsafe driving after the consumption of drugs with a fine or jail term, while the misdemeanor punishes driving under the influence of drugs with a lesser fine. Both punish unintentional but negligent violations.

In Germany I believe that involuntarily drinking alcohol may count as mitigating circumstances. Say your “friends” put vodka into your orange juice before you drove your car. Without your knowledge.

Now if you drink several orange juice with vodka: There is a first (low) limit where driving is still legal, above that it is illegal. More illegal with more drinks or if damage is done. There would also be a point where you notice that you are drunk so your excuse is gone, and another limit where you are incapable of making proper decisions. The judge would take these into account, and your “friend” might find themselves on the hook.

canada
No; these are mens rea offences.
The Criminal Code offences related to impaired operation of a vehicle (s. 320.14) do not expressly state a mens rea element, but the Supreme Court of Canada has said that criminal offences are presumed to have mens rea requirements of "intent, knowledge, or recklessness" (R. v. Sault Ste. Marie, [1978] 2 SCR 1299, p. 1325).
Accordingly, these offences have been interpreted to require the accused to have voluntarily consumed the substance or acted "recklessly, aware the impairment could result, but persisting despite the risk" (R. v. Mavin, 1997 CanLII 14625 (NL CA), at para 39). The accused can present evidence to raise a reasonable doubt "as to whether he was, through no fault of his own, disabled when he undertook to drive and drove, from being able to appreciate and know that he was" (The Queen v. King, [1962] SCR 746).

Mostly, yes
new-south-wales
The various offences are contained in s110 of the Road Transport Act 2013.
The prosecution merely has to prove that you were over the relevant prescribed range and were driving, occupying the driving seat and attempt to put the vehicle in motion, or instructing a learner driver to gain a conviction. They do not have to prove how you came to have that level of alcohol in your blood so, in that respect, the offence is strict liability.
There is one exception: if you are a "novice driver", charged with having a "novice range prescribed concentration of alcohol" (0.00-0.02) and you can prove that this was not as a result of consuming an alcoholic beverage (otherwise than for the purpose of religious observence) or the consumption of anything else (e.g. food or medicine) for the purpose of consuming alcohol, then that is a valid defence.

Also strict liability in vic.aus, no such "novice driver" exception.
